# Phantom SWT Button Images?

Tags: swt

I'm working on an old SWT (specifically, it's RCP) project and it has a virtual keyboard.  I added functionality to optionally have an image instead of a character.  When the button configuration is toggled from image back to button, it sometimes shows one of the *other* defined images AND the character.  I created a pop-up that reveals whether or not button.getImage() is null and when this phantom image is there, it is actually null, so the button *seems* to be constructed correctly, but is there some sort of dispose or redraw that I should be performing when switching back and forth between image and character?  Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

For control purposes, I created two buttons elsewhere in the application for testing and found that it still occurs:

```java
testButton = new Button(buttonBar, SWT.PUSH);
testButton.setText("Test Button");
testButton.setEnabled(true);
testButton.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (testButton.getImage() == null) {
            Image originalImage = new Image(Display.getDefault(), "EM-51.png");
            Image resizedImage = ImageUtils.resize(originalImage, 12, 12);
            testButton.setImage(resizedImage);
            originalImage.dispose();
            testButton.setText("");
        } else {
            testButton.setImage(null);
            testButton.setText("Test Button");
        }
    }
});
testButton1 = new Button(buttonBar, SWT.PUSH);
testButton1.setText("Test Button 1");
testButton1.setEnabled(true);
testButton1.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (testButton1.getImage() == null) {
            Image originalImage = new Image(Display.getDefault(), "EM-52.png");
            Image resizedImage = ImageUtils.resize(originalImage, 12, 12);
            testButton1.setImage(resizedImage);
            originalImage.dispose();
            testButton1.setText("");
        } else {
            testButton1.setImage(null);
            testButton1.setText("Test Button 1");
        }
    }
});
```

This is in Win7, Java 8_131, Eclipse Neon.

Here's an example of what I see.  The phantom image is behind the text in the right button.
[image: You can see the image behind the text in the right button]

Comment: What platform (macOS, Linux, Windows)?

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry, Windows

Comment: This seems to have been an issue with my enterprise build of Win7 or a bad update of Java 8.  It magically disappeared about a month later.

I'm not saying it was aliens, but...you know.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem Chris. What you are doing is that you are creating image each time you click on button.

**Solution:**

1. Create Image somewhere else, may be in constructor and reuse the
   same image. your code should not create image object at runtime,
   because creating image object is a heavy operation.

Code snippet: https://github.com/skumbha/testrepo/blob/master/TestDialog2.java

**Optional:**

2. Use testButton1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {}); instead of mouse down listener for buttons.( you will see lots of examples over net)
3. Use Jface Image registry to create image.
4. Looks like you are using JfaceDialog's "buttonbar", instead you can override createButtonsForButtonBar() method to create button in "buttonbar" and override buttonPressed()  method to add listeners for those buttons.

Code snippet: https://github.com/skumbha/testrepo/blob/master/TestDialog.java

You will get plenty of examples over net for each step.

Comment: I could have reproduce and fix the issue without using "ImageUtils" class, But in case you need a code snippet with ImageUtils class, please provide me the plugin name containing class "ImageUtils" class. Thanks

Comment: I should also mention that the code example above is a really simple example of a problem with the code that I'm working with.  It was originally written about 12 years ago, so it isn't using the most up-to-date methodologies.  The actual implementation is a virtual keyboard that allows images instead of characters and as the user toggles between different layouts, the images are displayed or removed.

Comment: @Shrirang_Kumbhar, I put the code for ImageUtils.resize here:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUmRoNTAwZWhYQXM

Comment: @ChrisClark, I have updated my answer with code snippet link. Please have a look. If you still face the issue, try creating two different image objects in constructor and use them in your two different listeners

Comment: I took both of your classes (they were awesome, thanks!) and ran them, but I still had the same problem:  http://imgur.com/a/dVeX4

However, I moved the code over to my Mac and it seems to have worked fine.  I think what we are seeing here is a problem with how the SWT buttons are working with Windows 7.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: @ChrisClark, I tried the code on Windows 7, Windows 10 and on Mac and it is perfectly working fine for me. I am using Java8,eclipse neon. Now the only point remaining is which version of SWT you are using? As your project code is 12 years old can you check the version of SWT/Jface you are using? I am using SWT3.10 and Jface3.12. There is possibility that your SWT/jface plugin version is not upgraded from long time. You can check it by looking at MANIFEST.MF file, dependency tab. Please share if you find something. thanks

Comment: @Shrirang_Kumbhar, I'm using 3.10 of SWT and 3.12 of jFace, but it also needs the org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt libraries to work.  If I remove them, it gives the `java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.` error, which I never could find a way around. Do you think this may be causing a problem?

Comment: I posted the whole project to github to show you what libraries I'm using:  https://github.com/cclark67/ButtonTest

Comment: @ChrisClark org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt is essential for E4 application. Can you please try 
 https://github.com/skumbha/testrepo/blob/master/TestDialog3.java. I suspect your machine is slow, I get Image and text at the same time rarely, but when I get it, image disappears in few milliseconds.

Comment: It still does the same thing.  Specifically, when one button is displaying the image and the other is displaying text and I mouse over the button with text, the image is displayed.  When I click the first button to get it to display text again, then mouse over the other button, the image disappears.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what I did, nothing would fix the phantom buttons.  I eventually gave up and was going to come back and worry about it later and it magically fixed itself a few weeks later.  I am guessing that it was a bug related to the graphics driver and how SWT was using it.  Java was updated and the drivers were updated during that period and no more phantoms.

Not the best way to resolve a problem, but I'll take it

¯\_(ツ)_/¯